# Yii - CGridView boolean date range

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I'd like to be able to search a date range in the CGridView filter.  Currently it is only possible to enter one boolean operator at the beginning of the filtered string.

Any ideas on how to alter this in order to be able to search a range of dates?

For example:

```
2010-04-24 > range < 2010-05-24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the approach I chose to take.  I created a View in MySql to include a duplicate date column.  This column needs an alias to avoid errors.

Then I updated my model to include the extra column in the rules() and search().

This works great, without too much hassle.

HOWEVER, I am not performing CRUD on this model, which may cause problems being that it's a View and not a Table in the database.